# Combining native app with worklight project

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a worklight application which needs file IO in it. I have written that code in  an android project separately. Can anyone tell me how I can combine the both of them into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Idan said, there's no way to port your existing native application to a Worklight Hybrid Application. However, you can take advantage of the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) that works out of the box with Worklight Hybrid Applications in different environments, such as Android and iOS. If you create a [Cordova Plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) you will need to create a plugin for all the environments you wish to support.

Here's a quick example of the File I/O API for [Writing a file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter):

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);  
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);
            writer.write(" different text");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Here's an example of [Reading](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) a file:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to combine an existing Worklight Hybrid application with an existing Native application. The correct approach for a Worklight application would be to write a Cordova plug-in to do what you want on the native side of things.

Please see these training modules which explain how to do just that: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova